# How to work on control inside Datagrid in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I m stuck in minor issue,which become time consuming as per my project concern,i am using datagrid in my wpf project in which my requirement is to show payment button only when status is "Not Paid",here i had use DataGridTemplateColumn in which i m using Button and on grid only i m getting status of payment.
Here is my xaml File

```
  <DataGrid Name="gridInvoiceList" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDetails}"  ColumnHeaderHeight="35"  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=pageControl, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   CanUserAddRows="false" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
       Width="978" RowHeaderWidth="20" RowHeight="25" 
           CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionChanged="gridInvoiceList_SelectionChanged" Height="220" LoadingRow="gridInvoiceList_LoadingRow" SelectionMode="Extended" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="160" Binding="{Binding FullName }" CanUserSort="True"   IsReadOnly="True"  />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Amount" Width="150" Binding="{Binding TotalAmount,ConverterCulture='en-GB',StringFormat=-{0:C}}" CanUserSort="True"  IsReadOnly="True"  />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Invoice Date" Width="200" Binding="{Binding InvoiceDate}" CanUserSort="True"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Payment Status" Width="220" Binding="{Binding PaymentStatus}" CanUserSort="True"  IsReadOnly="True"  />
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pay" Width="105">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Content="Pay" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Top"    Name="btnPay" Click="btnPay_Click"  />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Print" Width="105">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Content="Print" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Top"   Name="btnPrintInvoice"   Click="btnPrint_Click"   />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

I had use some code from reference code which had not fullfill my requirement

Comment: Let me know exactly what is the issue ?
Bind the button visibility to the property of payment and make it visible only the payment(Boolean) property is true.
Think about using Converters to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `converter` to achieve that. But I'll you show you the simplest, easiest way:

**Create a property:**

```
public System.Windows.Visibility PayButtonVisibility
{
    get
    {
        if (PaymentStatus == MyEnum.NotPaid)
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Then bind your button `visibility` to it:

```
<Button Content="Pay" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Top"    Name="btnPay" Click="btnPay_Click" Visibility="{Binding PayButtonVisibility}" />
```

Comment: I'm happy it worked out well for you. But I would recommend you to take a look into `Converters`. Will make your code look much better than that. :)